# Need help to work with videos and FFMPEG

Tags: 7

I am building a website that people upload a video and then they can cut a piece of the video. I am using FFMPEG.

I know how to do this using pure PHP, but since my website is based on Drupal, I prefer to use the Drupal modules.

I saw [PHP FFmpeg](https://www.drupal.org/project/php_ffmpeg) and [FFmpeg Wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffmpeg_wrapper) modules that work with FFMPEG. 
I would like to know is there any advantage in using these modules or using the pure PHP is preferable? Can these modules save the clipped videos as a node or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage these modules is assistance in managing your dependency on FFMPEG and how you want interface it in PHP code.

- PHP FFMPEG is a helper module for managing a dependency on the [PHP FFmpeg library](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg). If you want to use the PHP FFmpeg library, and require a Drupal module that will ensure your module has FFMPEG available to it, this module will help.
- FFmpeg Wrapper is a handful of custom functions that interface with FFMPEG via PHP's [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function. If your PHP environment can execute `passthru()` and you want some basic functions to execute some ffmpeg console commands, this module will help.

Both are API modules that don't provide any other integration with Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What functionalities are these modules APIs provide? For example consider this code `exec("ffmpeg -i yellowstone.mp4 -ss 00:03:07.5 -to 00:00:15  -c copy yellowstone_cut.mp4");`, which cuts some section of a video file. Is there any special function in these modules that does this? or I still need to use this pure PHP&FFMPEG code? I couldn't find any  tutorial  for these modules I would be appreciated for any tutorial link. Thanks.

Comment: Browse the source & docs to find the answer to that. Both are wrappers around the FFPEG binary; if it's supported you should find `-ss`, `-to` and other argument strings that get passed to the binary. PHP-FFMpeg appears to have a `clip()` method which looks like what you need. FFmpeg Wrapper is a pretty thin wrapper so it should be easier to find what options it supports than with PHP-FFMpeg's OOD.